# saving frames to a particular location in object detection

Tags: python, object-detection-api

I want to apply a check that if a folder with some frames in it already exists in a location then it should throw a message and skip that folder and check for the presence of next folder

I have made the script to save the frames having the bounding boxes and applied the check if a folder exists or not and if it exists then is it empty or not. If the check is not applied then the code works fine and all the frames in which object is detected are saved. But when check is applied then only 1 frame in all the folders is saved and the error message is also shown. How can i modify the code

```
def recognize_object(img_name, image):

    model_name='inference_graph'
    PATH_TO_CKPT="C:\\multi_cat_3\\models\\research\\object_detection\\inference_graph\\frozen_inference_graph.pb"
    PATH_TO_LABELS="C:\\multi_cat_3\\models\\research\\object_detection\\training\\labelmap.pbtxt"
    out="C:\\multi_cat_3\\models\\research\\object_detection\\my_imgs\\"+"video_"+vid_name

    os.makedirs(out,exist_ok=True)
    print(out)

    if os.path.exists(out) and os.listdir(out):
        print("Frames already processed for folder video_{0}".format(vid_name))
        pass
    else:

        NUM_CLASSES = 4

        label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
        categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
        category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

        detection_graph = tf.Graph()

        with detection_graph.as_default():
            od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
                serialized_graph = fid.read()
                od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
                tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

            sess = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)

        image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

        detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
        detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
        detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
        num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

        image_expanded = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

        (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run([detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],feed_dict={image_tensor: image_expanded})

        vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        image,
        np.squeeze(boxes),
        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
        np.squeeze(scores),
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=4,
        min_score_thresh=0.80,
        skip_scores=True)

        coordinates=vis_util.return_coordinates(
        image,
        np.squeeze(boxes),
        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
        np.squeeze(scores),
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=4,
        min_score_thresh=0.80)

        threshold=0.80

        objects = []
        z = 0
        for index, value in enumerate(classes[0]):
            object_dict = {}
            if scores[0, index] > threshold:
                object_dict[(category_index.get(value)).get('name')] = scores[0, index]
                objects.append(object_dict)
                print(objects)
            while (z<len(objects)):
                print({'File_Name':img_name,'Object_Detected':list(objects[z].keys())[0],'Probability':list(objects[z].values())[0]})
                z=z+1

        cv2.imwrite(out+"/{}.jpg".format(img_name),image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

If a folder has sub-folders A,B,C and if the code is run without the check being applied then inside every sub-folder multiple frames are saved in which object is detected. But the same does not happen when the check is applied although the message is displayed while every frame is being processed. Every sub-folder has only 1 frame after the code is executed. I want to save the same multiple frames even when the check is applied that were saved when the check wasn't applied